# Automatic Creation of user entry on C:\Users while creating a user with New-LocalUser

Tags: windows, powershell, script

This problem only consists of Local Users and has nothing to do with Active Directory. I think the question is self explanotary, I want C:\Users\UserName to be created as soon as I create a new user named UserName. I noticed that it only creates the directories after a restart and I have no idea how to do it without a restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new account is initialized on the first login, including all its folders.

Before the first login is done, Windows will not and can not
finish the creation of the account.

This is the way that creating an account works in Windows,
and it cannot be modified.

Comment: I see, thank you.